# Get Name / Description Startaddress Or From A Thread In A Process ( Delphi/Pascal )

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Process Hacker has a process manager in C.

When you double-click in process manager on a process e.g. Explorer
You see a lot of info, including:
Topics related to the process. PDD, Cycles Delta Start, Address, priority.

Well I tried to do something similar in Delphi, but I get only the TID and priority ...
I can not put the info Start Address as follows: "msiltcfg.dll 0x258!" or can only return
00630EFA.

The (Original) Application Process Hacker show the information in the image below:

[image: http://i54.tinypic.com/mrcztx.png]

How do I solve this? based on the code example below.

```
procedure TForm1.Button7Click (Sender: TObject);
var
  tbi: THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION;
  hThreadSnap, Process, hThread, ThreadInfo: THandle;
  te32: tagTHREADENTRY32;
  me32: MODULEENTRY32;
  th32: THREADENTRY32;
  dwPID: DWORD;

  startaddr: Pointer;
  Status: LongInt;
  Error: DWORD;
  modname: String;
  hToken: DWORD;
  TKP: TOKEN_PRIVILEGES;
  otkp: TOKEN_PRIVILEGES;
  dwLen: dword;


begin
  hThreadSnap: = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
  if hThreadSnap = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then 
   Exit;
  try
    dwPID: = GetProcessID (Trim (Edit1.Text));

    te32.dwSize: = SizeOf (THREADENTRY32);

    me32.dwSize: = SizeOf (MODULEENTRY32);

    ListBox1.Items.Clear;
    ListBox2.Items.Clear;

    if not Thread32First (hThreadSnap, te32) then
      Exit;

    repeat
      if te32.th32OwnerProcessID = dwPID then 
      begin
        hThread: = OpenThread (THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,
        False, te32.th32ThreadID);
        status: = ZwQueryInformationThread (hThread,
        9, 
        ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress {}
        @Startaddr,
        SizeOf (startaddr)
        @ DwLen);

        listbox1.Items.AddObject (Format ('StartAddress:% p'
        [Startaddr]) + 'ID:' + IntToStr(te32.th32ThreadID), TObject (hThread));

        if hThread <> 0 then
          CloseHandle (hThread);
      end;
    Until not Thread32Next (hThreadSnap, te32);
  finally
    CloseHandle (hThreadSnap);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I removed your emailadress, those whose answer do it below.

Comment: I think your real question should be more like this: "How do a do a stack traceback, or associate function names with their addresses, for a particular thread in an already running process".  My guess is that the answer is, that unless you have an application with debug symbols linked in, or an external .MAP or .TDS file, you can't.

Comment: Process Hacker is open source, so why don't you look at the source code?

Comment: @johnny, please do not fix code in questions. If there's a problem in there no answerer will know about it and everyone will get confused.

Comment: The process is open source hacker yeah ... but is done in C or C #. The 
implementation for Delphi / Pascal, based on the above code I need. 
I would if possible get help from you. The link shows the image and 
red box is selected the information they need to get this code.

Comment: This snippet of code I spent weeks reading a lot to get that 
result, but I can not in many ways that I tried to get precise. 
For this reason I come to the knowledge of you whom have very 
I certainly greater understanding. I program in Delphi to 3 years. If 
can supplement and explain the rest of the code so that I can 
learn also be grateful to their partners.

Comment: @Johan, I was hesitant to do it, but hey, someone else approved my suggestion.

Comment: @Johnny, edits almost always get approved as long as you don't put 'I #@$% you because you are a $%#%# #@#@#' stuff in there. The moderators just gloss over this stuff.

Comment: Johan, Can you help? have not got a solution, please? good 
Based on the code I posted. I need at least identify the file name 
MyLibrary.dll example linked to thread within the process eg: Explorer.exe

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at our logging class in the [Open Source SynCommons.pas](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/04/14/Enhanced-logging-in-SynCommons) unit: you can trace the stack of any method into the log file. If the .map (or its compressed .mab equivalence) is available, the line number will be displayed.

I'm working on a log viewer able to add source code lines during viewing, from a save .map/.mab file.

It's now used by the unit testing classes, so that any failure will create an entry in the log with the source line, and stack trace:

> C:\Dev\lib\SQLite3\exe\TestSQL3.exe 0.0.0.0 (2011-04-13)
>       Host=Laptop User=MyName CPU=2*0-15-1027 OS=2.3=5.1.2600 Wow64=0 Freq=3579545
>       TSynLogTest 1.13 2011-04-13 05:40:25
>
> 20110413 05402559 fail  TTestLowLevelCommon(00B31D70) Low level common: TDynArray "" stack trace 0002FE0B SynCommons.TDynArray.Init (15148) 00036736 SynCommons.Test64K (18206) 0003682F SynCommons.TTestLowLevelCommon._TDynArray (18214) 000E9C94 TestSQL3 (163)

The difference between a test suit without logging (TSynTests) and a test suit with logging (TSynTestsLogged) is only this:

```
procedure TSynTestsLogged.Failed(const msg: string; aTest: TSynTestCase);
begin
  inherited;
  with TestCase[fCurrentMethod] do begin
    fLogFile.Log(sllFail,'%: % "%"',
      [Ident,TestName[fCurrentMethodIndex],msg],aTest);
  end; {with}
end;
```

The `sllFail` level if used here, but you can use any available level.

Comment: I do not understand! As the base model code that could be posted as 
implement this .. not even know where to start, Please help me

Comment: @wederfs: A Bouchez said his product is open source. That means there is Delphi code available for it. You can use that to see how to do it. You have to do some work on your own (even when people give you the source).

Comment: The process is open source hacker yeah ... but is done in C or C #. The implementation for Delphi / Pascal, based on the above code I need. I would if possible get help from you. The link shows the image and red box is selected the information they need to get this code

Comment: This snippet of code I spent weeks reading a lot to get that 
result, but I can not in many ways that I tried to get precise. 
For this reason I come to the knowledge of you whom have very 
I certainly greater understanding. I program in Delphi to 3 years. If 
can supplement and explain the rest of the code so that I can 
learn also be grateful to their partners.

Comment: @wederfs As stated by my post, all logging is done in TSynLog class in SynCommons.pas unit, which is downloadable from our http://synopse.info/fossil site in its latest version, and is pure Delphi code, working from Delphi 6 up to XE. There is no C# and the C is only there to compile a SQlite3 engine, which you don't need here.

Comment: A. Bouchez,Hello, I'm glad you answered my post, I might not be 
understood very well by the fact that I'm in Brazil and my language is 
Portgues ... and my English is partly via translation software. you 
have MSN or Skype, if it is not uncomfortable like to have it on the list until 
because friendship is made anywhere in the world. I would be honored to 
may have a noble friends as anybody on the list. So help me to 
I made that statement in his answer. I'm waiting. If you want 
add me to messenger (weder.fs @ terra.com.br) or Skype (weder.fs)

Comment: @wederfs I don't use any messenger engine any more. No time for it. (I found out this is very time consuming) I don't any Facebook wall either. Sorry. I usually spend time here in StackOverflow, or in [our forums](http://synopse.info) - such discussion groups are public, therefore time spent in those could help other. That's what I like in OpenSource, and public sharing, when it deals with programing.